# Does rsync over ssh require use of UDP?

Tags: networking, ssh, rsync, nat

I have a remote rsync backup to a server running over ssh, using NAT to specify a non-standard high numbered port on the router.

Is it ok to only open the port on the router, and the ssh port on the server, to TCP connections, or is use of UDP required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH does not use UDP.

UDP is only used by alternative implementations like [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/).